# Reducing powers modulos

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Was working on a problem and reached this last part where I got an answer of $93^5 \bmod 95$. Anyone knows how to reduce $93^5 \bmod 95$ without using a calculator?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well $93\equiv -2\bmod 95$ so we have 
$$93^5\equiv (-2)^5\equiv (-1)^5\cdot 2^5\equiv -32\equiv 63\bmod 95$$